# how do you scroll through discord servers on the discord app?

Tags: discord

how do you scroll  through discord servers on the discord app?

I figured it out for how to do it on a laptop/desktop.. On that it's a mouse wheel or touchpad or autohotkey shortcut to simulate scrolling.

But how do you do it on android in the discord app?

Answer (score 1):

Swipe thought the servers icons on the left of the screen